# how to count in laravel collection?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, collections, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

this is collection i get:

```
 1 => App\Match_fact {#1332 ▼
      #guarded: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "match_facts"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:1 [▼
        "goals" => 3
      ]
      #original: array:1 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
  ]
}
```

i tried one option ->  `count($playerFacts->goals));` but it doesn't worked to me. I get error:
*Property [goals] does not exist on this collection instance.*

how to count all values got from the collection?

Comment: `$collection->count();`

Answer (score 0):

$playerFacts is collection then.

```
count($playerFacts);
```

Comment: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: sorry goals is number type, please check this count($playerFacts)